# Invalid use of non-static error member function arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to using the keypad library within another library. However, I got an "Invalid use of non-static error member function " error. I thought changing the functions to a static type would resolve the error but then the functions in the keypad library is not static and is causing more errors.

This is the error without changing the functions to static void

```sh
sketch\latch.cpp: In member function 'void latch::begin(int)':
latch.cpp:10:38: error: invalid use of non-static member function
   keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent);
                                      ^
exit status 1
invalid use of non-static member function
```

------------main.ino--------------

```cpp
#include "latch.h"
latch doorlatch;

void setup(){
  doorlatch.begin(9600);
  }
 void loop(){
  doorlatch.main();
  }
```

-----------cpp.h file------------

```cpp
#include "latch.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

latch::latch():keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, Rows, Cols ) {
}

void latch::begin(int baudrate){
  Serial.begin(baudrate);
  Serial.println("Latch library created");
  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent);

}

void latch::main(){
  keypad.getKey();
}
void latch::keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input){
  switch (keypad.getState()){
  case PRESSED:
  Serial.print("Enter: ");
  Serial.println(input);
  delay(10);
  }
}
```

------------h file-------------

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>

#ifndef _latch_
#define _latch_

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class latch {
  public:
    latch();
    void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);
    void begin(int baudrate);
    void main();
    Keypad keypad;
  private:
    const byte Rows = 4;
    const byte Cols = 4;

    char keys[4][4] = {
      {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
      {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
      {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
      {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
    };

    byte rowPins[4] = {7, 6, 5, 4};
    byte colPins[4] = { 11, 10, 9, 8 };
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The function

```cpp
class latch {
    ...
    void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);
    ...
};
```

is actually a **member function**, which means that it is implicitly assigned `latch *this` as additional parameter.

In order to solve this issue, make the function **static**:

```cpp
class latch {
    ...
    static void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);
    ...
};
```

or declare it as a **friend** of the class `latch`:

```cpp
class latch {
    ...
    friend:
        void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);
};

void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input)
{

}
```

I invite you to consult the vast online documentation about these two features in order to understand which approach suits your use-case better.

In either case, in the case that `latch` contains some stateful information which needs to be altered by `keypadEvent()`, then you may want want to use the [**singleton pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: I tried both of your methods, but other errors has occured. And I am strugging to unnderstand the singleton pattern

Comment: @wan I have personally tested both approaches and I can guarantee that they work as general solutions; However, your implementation may contain some errors; If you want further help, please open a new question with the new source code and error message.

Comment: when you said changing the function to a static function, do you just change it in the h file 

    'static void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);'

Answer (score 0):

I had the error with a different cause from Patrick Trentin. I had a function public function definition in a class `MPU9250`. The method was

```
void set_q_to_identity(){
   ...
}
```

In main.ino I called it as follows

```
mpu.set_q_to_identity();
```

which generated the invalid use of non-static member compiler error. After some experimentation I found the problem was the use of snake case in the method name.  If I changed this to camel case, then the program compiled successfully i.e.

```
void setQIdentity(){
   ...
}
```

and in main.ino

```
mpu.setQIdentity();
```

compiles successfully.